# What to test on a rest API?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring

I created a rest controller with Spring Boot, I am trying to learn what I should write on my tests, right now I only check status codes and keys existence. I am planning to build an API to showcase at interviews.

*I would like you to tell me what do you think of my tests class and what I should add*. I will use your advises to write the rest of the API tests.

Rest Controller

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/countries")
    public class CountryController {
    
        private final CountryRepository countryRepository;
    
        private final CountryModelAssembler countryModelAssembler;
    
        public CountryController(CountryRepository countryRepository, CountryModelAssembler countryModelAssembler) {
            this.countryRepository = countryRepository;
            this.countryModelAssembler = countryModelAssembler;
        }
    
        @GetMapping("/")
        public CollectionModel<EntityModel<Country>> getCountries() {
            List<EntityModel<Country>> countries = this.countryRepository.findAll()
                    .stream()
                    .map(this.countryModelAssembler::toModel)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            return CollectionModel.of(countries, linkTo(methodOn(CountryController.class).getCountries()).withSelfRel());
        }
    
        @GetMapping("/{id}")
        public EntityModel<Country> getCountry(@PathVariable Long id) {
            return this.countryRepository.findById(id).map(this.countryModelAssembler::toModel)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new CountryNotFoundException(id));
        }
    
        @PostMapping("/")
        public ResponseEntity<?> saveCountry(@RequestBody Country country) {
            EntityModel<Country> entityModel = this.countryModelAssembler.toModel(this.countryRepository.save(country));
            return ResponseEntity.created(entityModel.getRequiredLink(IanaLinkRelations.SELF).toUri())
                    .body(entityModel);
        }
    
        @PutMapping("/{id}")
        public ResponseEntity<?> editCountry(@RequestBody Country country, @PathVariable Long id) {
            Country updatedCountry = this.countryRepository.findById(id).map(mappedCountry -> {
                mappedCountry.setName(country.getName());
                return this.countryRepository.save(mappedCountry);
            }).orElseGet(() -> {
                    country.setId(id);
                    return this.countryRepository.save(country);
            });
            EntityModel<Country> entityModel = this.countryModelAssembler.toModel(updatedCountry);
            return ResponseEntity.created(entityModel.getRequiredLink(IanaLinkRelations.SELF).toUri())
                    .body(entityModel);
        }
    
        @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
        public ResponseEntity<?> deleteCountry(@PathVariable Long id) {
            this.countryRepository.deleteById(id);
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
        }
    
    }
```

Tests

```
@SpringBootTest
public class CountryControllerTest {

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "http://127.0.0.1:8085/countries";
    }

    @Test
    public void getCountries() {
        Response getResponse = RestAssured
                .when()
                .get("/")
                .then()
                .extract()
                .response();

        getResponse.prettyPrint();

        getResponse
                .then()
                .assertThat()
                .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value());

    }

    @Test
    public void saveCountry() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject country = new JSONObject();
        country.put("name", "Honduras");

        Response postResponse = RestAssured
                .given()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .body(country.toString())
                .when()
                .post("/")
                .then()
                .extract()
                .response();

        postResponse.prettyPrint();

        postResponse
                .then()
                .assertThat()
                .statusCode(HttpStatus.CREATED.value())
                .body("$", Matchers.hasKey("id"))
                .body("$", Matchers.hasKey("name"));
    }

    @Test
    public void getCountry() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject country = new JSONObject();
        country.put("name", "Panama");

        Response postResponse = RestAssured
                .given()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .body(country.toString())
                .when()
                .post("/")
                .then()
                .extract()
                .response();

        postResponse.prettyPrint();
        System.out.println("****************");

        postResponse
                .then()
                .assertThat()
                .statusCode(HttpStatus.CREATED.value())
                .body("$", Matchers.hasKey("id"))
                .body("$", Matchers.hasKey("name"));

        String jsonResponse = postResponse
                .getBody()
                .asString();

        String selfPath = new JSONObject(jsonResponse)
                .getJSONObject("_links")
                .getJSONObject("self")
                .get("href")
                .toString();

        Response getResponse = RestAssured
                .when()
                .get(selfPath)
                .then()
                .extract()
                .response();

        getResponse.prettyPrint();

        getResponse
                .then()
                .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value())
                .body("$", Matchers.hasKey("id"))
                .body("$", Matchers.hasKey("name"));
    }

    @Test
    public void editCountry() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject country = new JSONObject();
        country.put("name", "Costa Rica");

        Response postResponse = RestAssured
                .given()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .body(country.toString())
                .when()
                .post("/")
                .then()
                .extract()
                .response();

        postResponse.prettyPrint();
        System.out.println("****************");

        postResponse
                .then()
                .assertThat()
                .statusCode(HttpStatus.CREATED.value())
                .body("$", Matchers.hasKey("id"))
                .body("$", Matchers.hasKey("name"));

        String jsonPostResponse = postResponse
                .getBody()
                .asString();

        String selfReference = new JSONObject(jsonPostResponse)
                .getJSONObject("_links")
                .getJSONObject("self")
                .get("href")
                .toString();

        String newName = "Guatemala";

        country.put("name", newName);

        Response putResponse = RestAssured
                .given()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .body(country.toString())
                .when()
                .put(selfReference)
                .then()
                .extract()
                .response();

        putResponse.prettyPrint();

        putResponse
                .then()
                .assertThat()
                .statusCode(HttpStatus.CREATED.value())
                .body("$", Matchers.hasKey("id"))
                .body("$", Matchers.hasKey("name"))
                .body("name", Matchers.equalTo(newName));
    }

    @Test
    public void deleteCountry() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject country = new JSONObject();
        country.put("name", "Costa Rica");

        Response postResponse = RestAssured
                .given()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .body(country.toString())
                .when()
                .post("/")
                .then()
                .extract()
                .response();

        postResponse
                .then()
                .assertThat()
                .statusCode(HttpStatus.CREATED.value())
                .body("$", Matchers.hasKey("id"))
                .body("$", Matchers.hasKey("name"));

        postResponse.prettyPrint();

        String jsonPostResponse = postResponse
                .getBody()
                .asString();

        String selfReference = new JSONObject(jsonPostResponse)
                .getJSONObject("_links")
                .getJSONObject("self")
                .get("href")
                .toString();

        Response deleteResponse = RestAssured
                .when()
                .delete(selfReference)
                .then()
                .extract()
                .response();

        deleteResponse
                .then()
                .assertThat()
                .statusCode(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT.value());
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, when you call `RestAssured.when().get("/").then().extract().response();` in your tests, your Country controller is being called?

Comment: @AndresGardiol Yes it is being called, why?

Comment: Just to know, It's the first time I see the `RestAssured` class. To answer your question. I would recommend you to test as many cases as possible on each of your controller endpoints. You should test not only the "happy path", but also the cases where an error is expected. A great methodology for this is TDD (Test driven develpment)

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you get a country or id which isn't recognised?  Does your code throw the correct errors in such circumstances?

My (current, I still feel fairly new to writing good tests) approach is to look at all the inputs for a given method and ask myself: what could possibly get passed in, and how should the program handle it?

E.g. I want to delete countries with IDs 0, 5, -3, 7.392, -0.33333.  You might feel as though your project has been written so that invalid or nonsense values can't actually be sent to the method in the first place.  Maybe you are right.  However, maybe someone will find a way to hack it, or a future programmer will change something which then does accidentally allow the unwanted values to get through.  Assume *any* value of `long` could get through.  Write a different test for each and every variation you can think of.  Confirm that the correct action is taken, whether it's returning something, invoking another method, changing a class parameter, or throwing an error.